# Javascript function: something is not working

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I have a Javascript function in my application for validating a form and I am calling it on a button click. But the script is not working.

**SCRIPT**:

```
function payment() {
  alert("hi");
  var theuser = document.getElementById("<%=txtcardname.ClientID%>").value;
  var thecardno = document.getElementById("<%=txtcreditdet.ClientID%>").value;
  var thecvv = document.getElementById("<%=txtcvv.ClientID%>").value;
  var matchname = theuser.match(userRegex);
  var divcontent = document.getElementById("<%=errorcontent.ClientID%>");
  var msglbl = document.getElementById("<%=lblerror.ClientID%>");
  var ermsg = "";
  /*username validation*/
  if (matchname == null) {
    ermsg += "<li class='logli'>Username is Empty or Invalid.</li>";
  }
  /*Mobile validation*/
  if (themobile.length != 10) {
    ermsg += "<li class='logli'>Enter Your CardNumber Correctly.</li>";
  }
  /*Email validation*/
  if (thecvv.length!=3) {
    ermsg += "<li class='logli'>Enter Ur Cvv Correctly.</li>";
  }
  if (ermsg != "") {
    divcontent.style.display = "block";
    divcontent.style.background-colour="Aqua";
    divcontent.style.border = "1px solid #ff0000";
    divcontent.style.width = "100%";
    divcontent.style.margin = "0px 0 10px 15px";
    msglbl.style.display = "block";
    msglbl.style.margin = "0 0 15px 15px";
    msglbl.innerHTML = "Please correct the below errors" + "<ul>" + ermsg + "</ul>";
    return false;
  }
  return true;
}
```

**ASPX**:

```
<asp:Button ID="btnpay" runat="server" Text="PAY" CssClass="btnpaystyle" OnClientClick="if(!payment())return false;"/>
```

**NOTE**: I am calling the function `payment()` in the clientclick event of a button.

Comment: Which part isn't working?  Can you narrow it down?

Comment: @c0deNinja the function itself is not working.I tried giving a alert message also but script is not responding.

Comment: @user1537158: because that kind of snark is really helpful…

Comment: @smith269: what have you tried? have you tried clearing your browser cache, for example?

Comment: @andrewdotnich its working chrome but not in firefox OMG..

Comment: apology @andrewdotnich

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this out in your asp button:

OnClientClick="return payment();"